# Join LinkedServers

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

Joins are one of my weak points; I am never sure how to use them and this one is within an Openquery

This works when DBs are on the same Server:

```
SELECT top (100) FROM LocalDBl.dbo.LocalTable1
LEFT JOIN LocalDB2.dbo.LocalTable2 ON LocalTable1.id = LocalTable2.ID;
```

LocalDB2 was moved so trying to use linked Server

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([linkedServeronLocalDB1],'
SELECT TOP (100) FROM  LOCALDB1.dbo.TABLE1
LEFT JOIN REMOTE_DB.RemoteTable ON Table1.ID=RemoteTable.id');
```

I get "Deferred prepare could not be completed" and sometimes  not in sys.servers though it is there?

Any input is Appreciated

Comment: You're a query in [linkedServeronLocalDB1] linkedServer, are you sure that both your tables in your query are in the linked server.

Comment: if you have the two servers linked already, why not join directly by servername.dbname.schema.table?

Comment: It is not clear which instance you are connecting to and which instance contains the databases you need to reference. What you cannot do in OPENQUERY is refer to any table in any database that does not actually exist within that "remote" server instance. And no one but you knows what "REMOTE_DB.RemoteTable" refers to. Now might be a good time to seek help from the people that manage these server instances.